# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined AWS-SDK ec2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am designing an API to connect to AWS ec2 using aws-sdk on Node.js. I am getting the response from the AWS ec2. However, I am not able to send the received response using response.send. Please help me out.

The following is the API that I have designed.

```js
app.get("/getMachineList",function(req,res){
 console.log('getManageLabList API......')
  var params = {
  DryRun: false,
  Filters: [
    {
      Name: 'tag:Name',
      Values: [
        'abcd',
        /* more items */
      ]
    },{
      Name: 'instance-state-name',
      Values: [
        'running',
        /* more items */
      ]
    }
    /* more items */
  ]
  
};

ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ 
 accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
 secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
 apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});
 ec2.describeInstances( params, function(err, data, response) {
 if (err) {
  console.log("Error", err.stack);
 } else {
  console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
  response.send({
   message: data
  });
 }
 });


 
});
```

And this is the error I am getting.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the third parameter (response) from `describeInstances` callback, and change

```
response.send({
    message: data
});
```

to:

```
res.send({
    message: data
});
```

Comment: @Itamajs This solved the TypeError. But, I am not sure if the response is sent or not because I see nothing when I log the response. This is the HTTP request I am using...... `axios.get('http://localhost:3000/getMachineList')
   .then(response =>{
            return response
   console.log(response);
  })`

Comment: your `console.log` call is unreachable, because it is after the `return` statement. Please put it before the `return`

Comment: Oops, my bad. I overlooked that instruction! thank you @Itamajs